# Another Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression

Tags: java, exception, file-handling

This error is all over the internet and yet none of the "explanations" ever explain anything, nor do they fix my problem.

```
public Properties getProperties(String propertiesFileName)
{
    Properties prop;
    prop = new Properties();
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(propertiesFileName);
    prop.load(in);
    in.close();
    return prop;
    IOException localIOException;
    localIOException; //THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR
    localIOException.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

The line that says "localIOException;" is the cause of the error. Please tell me how I can fix this and/or why it's happening in the first place. Thanks.

EDIT:

Look at these 3 lines:

```
IOException localIOException;
localIOException;
localIOException.printStackTrace();
```

If I remove the middle line I get errors all over the place. For reasons I don't understand that middle line has to be there, but that's the line that causes my error.

Comment: What do you think that line should do?

Comment: Fix it by removing that line :)

Comment: not reachable code must be error... this code is not compilable.

Comment: @Wes If I comment that line I get errors on the few lines above it.

Comment: @Chechus the code is perfectly reachable. That's not the problem.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This code won't compile for me currently, but it DOES compile for the person who wrote the class. I don't have access to him, nor do I know what he's doing in his Eclipse environment to make this work, but it does. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Print your stack trace here...

Comment: It definitely does not.

Comment: It definitely DOES because I have a compiled jar file from this class that runs perfectly. Yet when I try to compile it I get the error.

Comment: You're probably misunderstanding what you are doing. No compiler that is Java-certified will correctly compile this code.

Comment: @EscobarCeaser no, is not compilable. There should be an if expression in somewhere else, currently does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
public Properties getProperties(String propertiesFileName)
{
    try {
        Properties prop;
        prop = new Properties();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(propertiesFileName);
        prop.load(in);
        in.close();
        return prop;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the compiler sees `localIOException;` as a higher priority error than the exception not being handled.

Answer (score 2):

The Java Language Specification forbids a line that does not conform to what it considers an expression. You don't call a method on the object or assign it to a variable, which is what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: This is not an answer (solution). You're simply pointing out the obvious. Please delete this and post a solution if you do not want to be down voted. Thanks.

Comment: The "solution" is to remove the line, and replace it with either a method call or an assignment. The compiler error is fairly straightforward here.

Comment: do you have an example of something that would work?

Comment: An answer is a solution that fixes the problem. Tom G did not do that. The answer I just posted fixes the problem so that is the answer I will accept.

Comment: I cannot magically deduce how you produced non-compilable source, nor do I have insight into your end goals for the code snippet. I assume at this point that you decompiled a JAR or something to produce the snippet shown. You asked for an explanation and multiple people provided one.

Comment: @TomG If you have no insight into my end goal, how could you pretend to provide an "answer" to my question? Again, an ANSWER is a SOLUTION that FIXES a problem. You did not even remotely provide a solution now did you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're accesing a file and you want to check for possible errors (using java exceptions), you ought to be using try/catch blocks:

For your code:

```
public Properties getProperties(String propertiesFileName)
{
    Properties prop;
    prop = new Properties();

    try
    {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(propertiesFileName);
        prop.load(in);
        in.close();
        return prop;
    }
    catch (IOException localIOException)
    {
        localIOException.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The code you're writing is equivalent to write:

```
int x;     // IOException localIOException;
x;         // localIOException; //THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR
```

That's what the error means, a variable's name by itself is not an expression for Java.